# Подключить jQuery-скрипт при условии

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Адаптирую сайт магазина для мобильных устройств. При просмотре с десктопа подпункты выпадают (`hover`, `absolute`), а для мобильных клиентов решил сделать разъезжающиеся пункты и подпункты ([пример на JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kb668aag/)).

Вопрос следующий: как подключать jQuery-скрипт только при определенном разрешении? Как поставить условие бы при большом размере области просмотра срабатывал обычный `css`, а на мобильных появлялась jQuery-анимация?

Вот скрипт ([больше по ссылке](http://jsfiddle.net/kb668aag/)):

```
var $menu_with_children = $('.has_children > a');

$menu_with_children.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.parent().find('> .sub-menu').hasClass('visible')) {
        $this.parent().find('> .sub-menu').addClass('visible').slideDown('slow');
    } else{
        $this.parent().find('> .sub-menu').removeClass('visible').slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Нужно что бы при определенных размерах области просмотра (например, больше 420px в ширину) ничего не менялось, а при меньше 420 подключался скрипт(css меняется медиа-запросами)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если необходимо, что бы условие срабатывало не только при инициализации скрипта, а и при изменении размера экрана, то нужно использовать обработчик. И проверять, как написал @installero, значение ширины экрана `$(window).width()`:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
  if ($(window).width() > 1280) {
    // код для окна больше 1280 пикселей
  } else {
    // код для окна меньше 1280 пикселей
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Есть как минимум две «ширины сайта» — ширина окна браузера и ширина документа (разница есть, например, если у пользователя появился скроллинг).

В jQuery `$(window).width()` и `$(window).height()` возвращают соответственно ширину и высоту области просмотра браузера.

Пользоваться ими можно, например, так

```
if ($(window).width() > 1280) {
  // Тут код для больших разрешений,
  // к примеру, с шириной окна с сайтом больше 1280 писелей
} else {
  // Тут код для маленьких экранов
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(($(window).width() > 1024)&&($(window).height() > 768)){
//что-то там...
} else {
//чего-то там...
}
```